# Convert CSV table into custom format

Tags: python, csv

I've got a CSV file that I'd like to convert into a different format. The CSV format is as follows:

```
A_to_B,B_to_C,C_to_D,...
0,2,1,...
```

I.e., each heading consists of two variables, e.g. A and B, and each row in the file contains a value that is either 0, 1, or 2. I'm trying to write a Python script that'll read this CSV file and turn it into a format like this:

```
A,B,0
B,C,2
C,D,1
...
```

In other words, it splits the first line which consists of headers into variables (e.g., A, B, C, D, etc.) and then matches the corresponding value for the new format. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I have some of the basics down, but the actual algorithm I can't get my head around properly. Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE #1**

Here's some code I have down, but I don't get the correct output:

```
import csv,sys

reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], 'rt'), delimiter=',')
headers = reader.next()

data = []

for row in reader:
    line = ','.join(row)
    data.append(line)

for row in data:
    for cols, val in zip(headers, row):
        newRow = cols[0], cols[-1], val
        print newRow
```

The CSV file looks like this:

```
A,B,C
0,2,1
0,1,1
```

However, output of the code looks like this, so I need a way to iterate over the CSV file in the correct way:

```
('A', 'A', '0')
('B', 'B', ',')
('C', 'C', '2')
('A', 'A', '0')
('B', 'B', ',')
('C', 'C', '1')
```

**UPDATE #2**

If anyone stumbles onto this, here's the code I ended up with (no error handling or anything, but it works):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv,os,sys

reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], 'rt'), delimiter=',')
headers = reader.next()
i = 1

for row in reader:
    os.system('rm id' + str(i) + '.csv')
    os.system('cat ./seeds >> id' + str(i) + '.csv')
    for srcdest,dist in zip(headers, row):
        sd = srcdest.split('_to_')
        src,dest = sd[0],sd[-1]
        if dist == '0':
            pass
        else:
            f = open('id' + str(i) + '.csv', 'a')
            f.write('{},{},{}\n'.format(src.lower().replace('_',''),dest.lower().replace('_',''),float(dist)))
    i=i+1

f.close()
```

*Thank you for your help everyone!*

Comment: Can you edit the formatting on your post?  It looks like you want stuff on different lines, but each of your data examples is showing up as just one line.  This makes it hard to understand what output format you want.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for picking that up. @BrenBarn

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility:

```
>>> header
[u'A_to_B', u'B_to_C', u'C_to_D']
>>> data
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> for row in data:
...     for cols, val in zip(header, row):
...         newRow = cols[0], cols[-1], val
...         print newRow
(u'A', u'B', 0)
(u'B', u'C', 1)
(u'C', u'D', 2)
(u'A', u'B', 0)
(u'B', u'C', 2)
(u'C', u'D', 1)
(u'A', u'B', 1)
(u'B', u'C', 2)
(u'C', u'D', 3)
```

As shown, this assumes you have a "header" thing that has a list of the column names, and a "data" thing that is a list of rows.  (This is basically what you get if you use the csv module from the standard library.)  It outputs a new list of rows.

In this example I assumed all the column names were just one letter, so I could access them as the first and last characters of the "A_to_B"-style column name.  If your column names have differing lengths you could use `cols.split('_')` to split on the delimiter and extract the two column names.  But that's just a string parsing problem kind of tangential to your main question.

Edit in response to your edits:

Remove your first `for` loop.  The data from csv.reader is already in the format you want; by doing your `','.join'` you are repackaging it into a format you don't want.  Your second for loop should iterate directly over the reader:

```
>>> for row in reader:
...     for cols, val in zip(headers, row):
...         newRow = cols[0], cols[-1], val
...         print newRow
```

The other problem is that the data you posted in your edit is not the same format as the original.  You initially said that the columns were of the form "A_to_B", "B_to_C", etc., but in your second example the columns are just "A", "B", "C", etc.  You need to explain how you intend to derive the new column names from the original column names.

Comment: How do I create the "data" thing into a list like that? Whenever I read the CSV file I get output that looks like this: ['0', '2', '1']. Instead, I want to treat each row as a single item in a list like your example. @BrenBarn

Comment: Look at the documentation for the csv module: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html .  This module lets you iterate over rows of the input file.

Comment: I've added some code and output, but I'm stuck again. @BrenBarn

Answer (score 0):

Read in the data so that

```
row1 = ['A_to_B','B_to_C',...]
row2 = [0,2,1,...]
```

which might be done by simply opening the file, reading in the line, and splitting it on commas. You might also want to use the `csv` module in the standard library. Once you have that you can do something like:

```
for srcdest,dist in zip(row1,row2):
    sd = srcdest.split('_')
    src,dest = sd[0],sd[-1]
    f.write('{},{},{}\n'.format(src,dest,dist))
```

where `f` is the destination file. You might also use the `csv` module to write the rows, but it might be easier just to write a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip

with open("myfile.csv") as inf, open("new.csv","w") as outf:
    header = [s.split('_to_') for s in inf.next().split(',')]
    for row in inf:
        nums = (int(s) for s in row.split(','))
        for (_from, _to), num in izip(header, nums):
            outf.write("{},{},{}\n".format(_from, _to, _num))
```